# How to do explicit loading for multiple entries in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I see a few explicit loading examples on the web like this:

ref: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

```
using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var student = (from s in context.Students
                            where s.StudentName == "Bill"
                            select s).FirstOrDefault<Student>();

        context.Entry(student).Collection(s => s.Courses).Load();
    }
```

Or ref: http://codingcanvas.com/loading-nested-entities-in-entityframework/

```
using (var context = new EmployeeContext())
            {
                var employee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault();
                context.Entry(employee).Reference(x => x.ContactDetails).Load();
                context.Entry(employee).Reference(x => x.EmpDepartment).Load();
                context.Entry(employee.EmpDepartment).Collection(x => x.DepartmentProjects).Load();
            };
```

//SQL Generated --------------------------------------------

```
SELECT TOP (1) 1.[EmployeeNo]          AS [EmployeeNo],
               1.[FirstName]           AS [FirstName],
               1.[LastName]            AS [LastName],
               1.[Age]                 AS [Age],
               1.[DepartmentId]        AS [DepartmentId],
               1.[FunctionId]          AS [FunctionId],
               1.[TypeOfEmployee]      AS [TypeOfEmployee],
               1.[Project_ProjectCode] AS [Project_ProjectCode]
FROM   [dbo].[Employees] AS 1

SELECT [Extent1].[EmployeeNo]   AS [EmployeeNo],
       [Extent1].[Address]      AS [Address],
       [Extent1].[Phone]        AS [Phone],
       [Extent1].[Fax]          AS [Fax],
       [Extent1].[Mobile]       AS [Mobile],
       [Extent1].[LocationCord] AS [LocationCord]
FROM   [dbo].[EmployeeContacts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[EmployeeNo] = 1 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */

SELECT [Extent1].[DepartmentId]   AS [DepartmentId],
       [Extent1].[DepartmentCode] AS [DepartmentCode],
       [Extent1].[DepartmentName] AS [DepartmentName]
FROM   [dbo].[Departments] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[DepartmentId] = 11 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */

SELECT [Extent1].[ProjectCode]             AS [ProjectCode],
       [Extent1].[ProjectName]             AS [ProjectName],
       [Extent1].[ProjectDescription]      AS [ProjectDescription],
       [Extent1].[Department_DepartmentId] AS [Department_DepartmentId]
FROM   [dbo].[Projects] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  ([Extent1].[Department_DepartmentId] IS NOT NULL)
       AND ([Extent1].[Department_DepartmentId] = 11 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */)
```

That is great, but if I remove `FirstOrDefault()` and put `Where(x=> x.Age > 20)` it returns me a collection not just TOP(1). I can't use `context.Entry(employee)` any more right? since it is only suitable for a single entry object.

Now, how do I do the same as the examples, but instead of single entry we use `Where` to select multiple entries and load their references?

Comment: You should be able to do something like `context.Students.Include("Courses").Where(... rest of your logic here... )`

Comment: @Rob, I just find that when Include() gets a bit more complicated, EF joins starts to get messy, in my case I did 4 tables, it results in a query longer than 30sec. If I do select these tables one by one, it only takes less than a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Entry** method give you the control over an entity attached to the current context, so before use it the entity must be attached.

The only way to achieve your target is to cycle on all your retrieved entities and **Load** referenced data.

```
using (var context = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            var employee = context.Employees.Where(x=> x.Age > 20);
            foreach( var item in employee)
            {
                context.Entry(item).Reference(x => x.ContactDetails).Load();
                context.Entry(item).Reference(x => x.EmpDepartment).Load();
                context.Entry(item.EmpDepartment).Collection(x => x.DepartmentProjects).Load();
            }
        };
```

Obviously much depends on how many records you are facing, IMHO, if your Foreign Keys and Indexes are optimized, the **Include** (then a JOIN database side) is the best choice, because all data are retrieved with a single database call, but indeed in some cases more different single SELECT could be a valid option.

Comment: For those who seek the same answer, Include() will do the job as Luca said. IF you have correct indexes and fkeys. I indexed and fkeyed the correct cols, and wala, result came up in 2 seconds. not 2 minutes.

Comment: Will this generate a new query for every `foreach` cycle (i.e., for each employee)?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Worse. It will generate and execute 3 queries for each Employee. This code really should not be used in production.